# How to remove the null before resultant string after concatenation..?

Tags: java, string

How to remove the null after concatenation of two strings.

```
Ex:
String a = null;
String b = Hello;
a+=b;
System.out.println(a);// output is nullhello
```

here, i need output as only hello,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `String a = "";`

Comment: @Eran thank for your quick response, but after that i need to check whether a is null or not but not empty.

Comment: "Hello" needs to be in quotes.. minor typo there

Comment: @SurajRao: Pedantically, `Hello` might be a reference to a string.

Comment: @Bathsheba yeah sure.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this

```
 String a = null;
 String b = "Hello";
 a = ((a==null) ? "": a) + b;
 System.out.println(a);
```

Comment: What if `b == null`?

Comment: @oleg.cherednik In that case, you can perform the same check for b.
a = ((a == null) ? "" : a) + ((b == null) ? "" : b)

Answer (score 2):

The Java designers thought it a good idea to treat the compound assignment by sum operator `+=` when applied to a `null` lvalue `java.lang.String` reference as a special case by injecting a (rather arbitrary) textual stringification of nullness.

(I see it as a manifest act of utter madness: an alternative would include throwing a `NullPointerException` as would happen if `+=` is applied to a numeric boxed type such as `java.lang.Integer`.)

If you don't want this behaviour then you need to program specifically to obviate it.

Comment: That's why C# didn't copy this feature.

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom method for this, this is one line of code:

```
public static String concat(String a, String b) {
    return a == null ? b : b == null ? a : a + b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be a bit of overhead, but you can use [Objects.toString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#toString(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String)) method:

```
String a = null;
String b = Hello;
System.out.println(Objects.toString(a,"").concat(Objects.toString(b,"")));
```

> public static String toString(Object o,
>                 String nullDefault)
>
> Returns the result of calling toString on the first argument if the
>   first argument is not null and returns the second argument otherwise.

This will handle all the possible cases {(a == null, b!= null),(a != null, b == null),(a == null, b == null),(a != null, b!= null)}

other alternative will be using [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html)

```
System.out.println(
        Optional.ofNullable(a).orElse("")
                .concat(Optional.ofNullable(b).orElse(""))
);
```

> public T orElse(T other)
>
> Return the value if present, otherwise return other.

This will be identical to the first solution. Both of this solutions has one common disadvantage: code needs to be duplicated for every additional variable. For example if now we need to concatenate 3 variables `a`,`b` and `c`. We will have to just copy and paste same code for `c`.

In this case we can use `Streams`

```
System.out.println(
        Stream.of(a,b)
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .collect(Collectors.joining())
);
```

It will create a stream consisting of strings `a` and `b`; will filter out all strings which are null and finally collect all remaining strings using empty delimiter. In case if there are more then 2 variables we will just add them to initial stream.

I hope you will find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You may use Google's [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki) library to get rid of null before concatenation.

```
String a = Strings.nullToEmpty(null);
String b = Strings.nullToEmpty("Hello");
a+=b;
System.out.println(a);// output is hello
```

It makes the code more explicit about the fact that you don't want null, IMO it's more readable as than a ternary expression.

Comment: Only use third-party libraries if you're already using them for something else. Otherwise, just use plain Java `Objects.toString(a, "")`.

Comment: You can always use Guava for something else. It's not that expensive in term of size